# Print File Descriptions from all files in a folder, wmic command

Tags: windows, cmd, wmic

This works

```
for /r "D:\FOLDER\" %i in (*) do @echo %i
```

But this doesn't

```
for /r "D:\FOLDER\" %i in (*) do @wmic datafile where name=%i get Description
```

using reference from first command, I wrote `wmic` command. but It doesn't work.

gives multiple errors...

```
Node - <MACHINE NAME>
ERROR:
Description = Invalid query
```

What's the problem here. How do I print file descriptions of all files in a folder.

**Update**: Added `''` around `%i`

```
for /r "D:\FOLDER\" %i in (*) do @wmic datafile where name='%i' get Description
```

Now it gives me `No Instance(s) Available.` error?

**Question**: Why `wmic datafile get description` doesn't give file description in file properties dialog box? How to get the file description.

[image]

Comment: Are you executing this command directly in command prompt or in a batch file? for the latter, you'll need to write `%%i` rather than `%i`...

Comment: what if typing the `wmic` command directly, without `for`? maybe its sytax is wrong?

Comment: You can try these commands on your machine, all I want is File Description

Comment: Read [WMIC Best practices](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758713(v=ws.10).aspx) to see how-to query datafile class, e.g. `WMIC DATAFILE WHERE Name="c:\\boot.ini"`. Note doubled backslashes.

Comment: That's exactly how I did it. You find any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the same output and a lot faster using

```dos
dir /s /b "D:\FOLDER\*"
```

But, as the question is how to do it with queries to `wmic` for each file

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /r "d:\folder" %%a in (*) do (
        set "folder=%%~pa"
        for /f "tokens=* delims=." %%x in (".%%~xa") do (
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            for %%b in ("!folder:\=\\!") do (
                endlocal 
                wmic datafile where ^
                  "drive='%%~da' and path='%%~b' and fileName='%%~na' and extension='%%~x'" ^
                get description | find ":"
            )
        )
    )
```

This code handles two "problems" in the `wmic` queries: paths need to have backslashes doubled and file extension are stored without starting dot.

**edited** As it seems that the OP needs metadata from the file contents and not the data available from `wmic`,

```dos
@if (@this==@isBatch) @then 
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :listFilesProperties "d:\folder"
    goto :eof

:listFilesProperties folder    
    cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~f0" "%~f1"
    goto :eof

@end  
var folderNameSpace = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application").NameSpace(WScript.Arguments.Item(0));

    for (
        var fileEnum = new Enumerator(folderNameSpace.Items());
        !fileEnum.atEnd();
        fileEnum.moveNext()
    ){
        var fileName = fileEnum.item();
        var fullPath = folderNameSpace.GetDetailsOf(fileName, 180);
        var title  = folderNameSpace.GetDetailsOf(fileName, 21);
        WScript.Echo( fullPath + '|' + title );
    };
```

This is an hybrid batch/jscript file that will retrieve the properties of the files in the indicated folder, in this case the full path and file title.

Comment: by "file description" i mean description in file properties dialog box, Select a ms office executable office, go to file properties, there you see the file description which is different from file name. Your script works, but it prints file names. dir /s /b "folder" will do that, you are right. I want "file description"

Comment: which wmic command param refers to "file description", why does wmic datafile get description  prints file name... Strange

Comment: @user1, as far as i know, the kind of metadata you are trying to read is not available in wmi classes, so `wmic` can not retrieve it. You can use other methods, but not from pure batch. I've included a sample of how to query the `title` (not sure about what exact propertie you need)

Comment: Awsome answer! Thank you very much

Comment: @user1, it is easier  `for /r "d:\folder" /d %%a in (.) do call :listFilesProperties "%%~fa"` avoiding a recursive search in the jscript code. Change the script part only if the number of folders is really big or performance is critical